# how to sort records in csv files using particular column in java

Tags: java

I'm reading student data from csv file and trying to sort data in descending order by using marks column and trying to get top n and last n student records. I'm facing problem how to sort complete csv file by particular column and where to store that sorted data and how to retrieve top n student records.

I tried using the below code to sort marks column. By using that I can sort that column but I can't get remaining fields like name, roll number and phone num.

```
String splitBy = ",";
String line = "";
ArrayList<String> marks = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Student_Records.csv"));
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
    //System.out.println(b[5]+" && "+b[6]);
    marks.add(b[7]);
}
List<Integer> newList = marks.stream()
    .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.sort(newList, Collections.reverseOrder());
for(int i : newList)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your current attempt at solving this & what specific problem(s) you are having with that attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing only the marks in the list that you create. You need to store the other data that you want as well.

Instead of using a `List<String>` and converting to a `List<Integer>`, you could create a new class, ie: `StudentRecord`. That class could have fields for the values in your csv, such as a mark field, a name, etc.. Then you can put them into a `List<StudentRecord>`.

If you do that, your problem becomes "How do I sort a list of objects based on one of their fields?" You can use the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interfaces to decide how you want to sort them.

To see many examples of how to use either of those interfaces, you can Google "java comparator examples" or "java comparable examples".

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this should at least give you a start (I don't have a csv to test it):

```
    //Loading file into a List
    String splitBy = ","; 
    String line=""; 
    List<List<String>> marks = new ArrayList<>(); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Student_Records.csv")); 
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ 
        String[] b = line.split(splitBy); 
        //System.out.println(b[5]+" && "+b[6]);
        marks.add(Arrays.asList(b)); 
    } 

    //Creating the comparator
    Comparator<List<String>> comp = new Comparator<List<String>>() {
        public int compare(List<String> marksLine1, List<String> marksLine2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(marksLine1.get(7)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(marksLine2.get(7))); //Change the 7s to the column index you want to sort by (I assume 7 is your marks column)
        }
    };
    //Sorting using the comparator
    Collections.sort(marks, comp);

    //Printing the sorted csv
    for(List<String> i : marks) 
        System.out.println(i.toString());

    //Close the BufferedReader
    br.close();
```

I used List instead of just ArrayList so that it can hold the entire csv data.  ArrayList is only capable of holding a single line unless you wrap it in another list.  Basically the first list holds the data horizontally, then you need the 2nd list wrapped to hold the data vertically.

Additionally I created a custom comparator where you can edit to sort it according to what you need.  You also may need to throw or catch an IOException if you try this out.

Comment: @GeethaTabjul Please flag the question as completed, thanks.